# Android AVD emulator can't load driver swrast on Vagrant machine

Tags: cordova, vagrant, ubuntu-14.04, android-virtual-device

I'm using Cordova to build an app. I'm running **Android SDK** on a **Vagrant VM** with **Ubuntu 14.04**. When I try to emulate Android i get the following error:

```
$ cordova emulate android
Running command: /home/vagrant/sync/www/fitfortime/app/platforms/android/cordova/run --emulator
WARNING : no emulator specified, defaulting to cordovakitkat
Waiting for emulator...
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
emulator: warning: opening audio output failed

X Error of failed request:  GLXUnsupportedPrivateRequest
  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (X_GLXVendorPrivate)
  Serial number of failed request:  170
  Current serial number in output stream:  172
```

I followed this tutorial to set up my environment: 
http://flurdy.com/docs/android/cordova_vagrant_android.html

Comment: Did you saw this question? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36189393/android-studio-avd-error-launching)

It worked for me and my problem. But it wasn't exactly the same problem as yours.