# Cannot launch AVD in Android Studio (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I'm trying to launch newly created `AVD` and that's what I've got:

> Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
>      Output:
>      libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
>       libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
>       libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
>       X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
>         Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
>         Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
>         Serial number of failed request:  49
>         Current serial number in output stream:  48
>       libGL error: unable to load driver: nouveau_dri.so
>       libGL error: driver pointer missing
>       libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
>       libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
>       libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
>       X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
>         Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
>         Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
>         Serial number of failed request:  49
>         Current serial number in output stream:  48

What happened and how can I fix that?

Comment: are you using 32-bit system? Did you install Oracle JDK 8

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36189393/android-studio-avd-error-launching   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35911302/cannot-launch-emulator-on-linux-ubuntu-15-10

Comment: This all looks like to revolve around your VGA/GPU subsystem. Are you using nouveau or nvidia's proprietary driver? What's your hardware, are you using hybrid technologies like PRIME and optimus?