# Fail load emulator in debian with android studio 3.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, debian

I create a virtual device with AVD Manager in AndroidStudio.
but when start device raise this errors:

```
libGL error: unable to load driver: nouveau_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  33
  Current serial number in output stream:  34
```

how can i fix it?

Comment: did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36189393/android-studio-avd-error-launching)

Comment: @GautamChibde yes, I tried, but never answers can not help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I install Video Card Drivers and my problem resolved.